# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid error when trying to test React Component using Jest/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have found these issues elsewhere but not quite in the same situation as myself and am therefore struggling to find a solution for the problem. In my case, the component works fine but I get this error when trying to mount it:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `RepoDropdown`.
```

I want to mount it so that I can test the onChange part of the select component I have created. The component looks like this:

```
const SelectRepo = styled.select`
  // CSS rules here
`;

export class RepoDropdown extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    // Logic here
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.repoList) {
      return null;
    }

    const repoItems = this.props.repoList.map(repo => (
      <RepoDropdownItem repo={repo.name} key={repo.id} />
    ));

    return (
      <SelectRepo onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {repoItems}
      </SelectRepo>
    );
  }
}

RepoDropdown.propTypes = {
  // Required propTypes here
};

export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  repoList: getAllRepos(state),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getRepoInfo, updateCurrentUrl, updateWrongRepo }
)(RepoDropdown);
```

This is the way that I am trying to mount the component:

```
it('SHOULD call onChange function when new repo is selected', () => {
  const middlewares = [thunk];
  const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
  const initialState = {
    repos: {
      repoList: [{ name: 'sample1', id: 1 }, { name: 'sample2', id: 2 }],
    },
  };
  const store = mockStore(initialState);

  const component = mount(
    <DefaultThemeProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RepoDropdown
          getRepoInfo={getRepoInfo}
          repoList={[
            { name: 'the-value', id: 1 },
            { name: 'not-the-value', id: 2 },
          ]}
          updateCurrentUrl={updateCurrentUrl}
          updateWrongRepo={updateWrongRepo}
        />       
      </Provider>
    </DefaultThemeProvider>
  );

  component
    .find('select')
    .simulate('change', { target: { value: 'sample1' } });
  expect(component.find('select').prop('onChange')).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I have tried various fiddling with imports and exports to try and fix this as this was suggested elsewhere but to no avail. I feel that it is something to do with the child components being rendered but have not been able to find a fix to resolve this.

Comment: What is your SelectRepo component? Could you post some code for that as well please?

Comment: @Marcus It's a styled <select> element. The styled component is defined at the top of the code.

Comment: OK- a couple of things then: could you give the select a classmate and try and search for that instead? Also, I’m not sure you should be returning null from your render method; while I’m not sure this is necessarily wrong, try putting that condition in the parent and only render a RepoDropdown if the injected list is going to be non-empty?

Comment: @Marcus I just tested returning null in the render and it seems to be ok for React.

Comment: Do you have any other files inside the same directory with the same name? If so, either change the name of the other file or declare the file extension. For example, if you have `example.js` and `example.css` and you import `./example` inside of your test, it can resolve to the `css` file instead of the `js` file.